# Is there a way to vectorize seq() and grep() to use on conjunction with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, vectorization

Apologies if this is obvious, I don't have much experience with R. I have a function `contains_leap_year(date1, date2)` that I want to pass in as a condition to `dplyr::if_else()`.

My for loop implementation looks like this

```
contains_leap_year <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if (df$date1[i] < 0 & !is.na(df$date2[i])) {
        seq_str <- seq(df$date1[i], dat$date2[i], by = "day")
        res <- (length(grep("-02-29", seq_str)) > 0)        
    }
    else {
        res <- FALSE
    }

    contains_leap_year <- append(contains_leap_year, res)
}
```

Then I would append this column to my dataframe, and do something like

```
dplyr::mutate(
    res = dplyr::if_else(contains_leap_year == TRUE, action1, action2)
)
```

But this is rather slow. Ideally, I'd like to work within `dplyr` the whole time like so

```
dplyr::mutate(
    res = dplyr::if_else(length(grep("-02-29", seq(date1, date2, by = "day"))) > 0, action1, action2)
)
```

However, just doing this throws `'from' must be of length 1` error, which I believe is because `date1` and `date2` are vectors, so `seq` cannot construct the sequence.

If this isn't possible, is there an alternative method that is faster than just a for loop?

Comment: Maybe you should try leap_year function from lubridate. https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/leap_year.html

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that helps my use case. Perhaps a better name for my function would be contains_leap_day. For example, if I look at the date range 2012-06-30 to 2013-06-30, 2012 is a leap year, but this range does not contain a leap day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not ideal, I've settled (for now) on just looping over the vector, but using `furrr::future_map2` to do so. I don't have any rigorous benchmarks, but it's about 2.5x faster than `purr::map2` on my dataset, and something around 10x faster than a for loop.

Example function

```r
contains_leap_day <- function(x, y) {
    date_seqs <- format(seq(x, y, by = "day"))
    res <- (length(stringr::str_which(date_seqs, "-02-29")) > 0)
    
    return(res)
}

future::plan(multisession)
df %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
        has_leap_day = furrr::future_map2(year1, year2, contains_leap_day, .progress = TRUE)
    )
```